# C# Sql Connection String Copy Paste Still giving errors

Tags: c#

I am having this issue that when I copy/paste the connection string of my Database, I'm still getting build errors as can be seen in the image attached. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

I've highlighted the issue for your ease.

Regards.

Connection String:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Fahad Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Apps\ECOInv\ECOInv\inventory.mdf";Integrated Security=True);
```

[image]

Comment: You are not escaping the double quotes in the string properly

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi is right, and escape back-slashes as well

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you guys help me with correcting that? I'm very new to this coding scene.

Comment: @FahadAhmed this is why you need to post your errors and codes directly instead of images.

Comment: Post your code, error and connection string as *text*, not images. Images can't be copied , compile, googled or used to reproduce a problem

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Fahad Ahmed\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Apps\ECOInv\ECOInv\inventory.mdf";Integrated Security=True);

Comment: @FahadAhmed When you have a string that starts with `@` (like you have) then any `"` character inside the string must be doubled.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by Captain Kenpachi you are not escaping the quote sign in the connection string, so C# thinks that `C:\Users` is supposed to be code, rather than part of the connection string.

To define a string in code you use quotes to indicate the beginning and end of a string, as in the below code snippet.

```cs
string variable = "value";
```

However, sometimes you need a quote character to be part of a string. This can be done by escaping the character. In C# you can do this by prepending the character by a forward slash, as in the following code.

```cs
string variable = "This is in \"quotes\" so will be parsed properly";
```

This allows you to have characters interpreted literally, instead of semantically.

Note that, since you begin your string with the `@` character, the compiler will interpret the entire string literally, preventing you from using escape sequences such as these, with the advantage that you can use forward slashes as regular characters, instead of having to escape them.

For verbatim string literals you can escape the quote character by doubling them such as in the example below.

```cs
string variable = @"This ""quoted text"" will work as well";
```

Comment: This is correct in general but if you try to write in the VS editor the OP failing line you will discover that in this case it will not work

Comment: Good point! I updated my answer to account for that.

Comment: You *can* escape quotes by simply doubling them in `@` strings.

Comment: I wasn't actually aware of that. Writing up this answer is turning out to be more of a learning experience for me than for whoever asked the question!

Comment: No way to test it now, but probably the whole path could be simply put inside single quotes